# Binding an Angular 2 array in the template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a component that looks something like this:

```
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector : 'radio-select',
  ...
})
export class RadioToggleSelect {
  @Input() options : Array<string>;
}
```

Now I'd like to bind to the array in the HTML, such as something like:

```
 <radio-select options='["Users", "Account Holders"]'> </radio-select>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular 2  For Property Binding target property should be surrounded its name with `[]` , which is one way binding from model to view. it should be as below

```
[options]='["Users", "Account Holders"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `[]` the value is treated as plain string. Use this instead:

```
<radio-select [options]='["Users", "Account Holders"]'> </radio-toggle-select>
```